Gradle variants Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment
I'm adding the OpenRewrite plugin plus recipe dependencies to a Gradle project which then complains about unmatched attributes in variants.
I can't really figure out how to read this report and how to fix it. Is it an issue with OpenRewrite or is there an issue with my dependencies?
I'm using the Gradle toolchain
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(javaVersion)
    }
}


Gradle version/wrapper is 8.10.1
OpenRewrite is open-rewrite =
"6.28.1"
open-rewrite-recipe-bom = "2.23.0"

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':docsTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve root project :.
     Required by:
         root project :
      > The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 21, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally. However we cannot choose between the following variants of root project ::
          - rewrite
          - runtimeElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'rewrite' capability 'at.martinahrer:continuousdelivery:unspecified' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 21)
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability 'at.martinahrer:continuousdelivery:unspecified' declares a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 21, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)


Hi! What version of the Gradle plugin would you be using here?

I have added the version information to the question as I think it should have added it there from the first place.
